# Div auto scroll (Mobile)

Tags: javascript

I need to be able to make a div scroll from left to right and then move back to the start or bounce and loop over. Although when the 'app' is selected the scrolling stops.

The version i want to scroll can be found at etreecycle.co.uk on web by making the page a mobile size or by viewing the site on a small device.

The basic layout is;

```
<div id="scroll-me"> // Only scroll when the page is less then 650px wide.
<div id="app-wrapper"> // Changes width to make the contence responcive, this will be 3240px wide and 270px high when it is scrolling.
    <div id="app"></div> // the apps have the hover tag, when hovering the scrolling needs to stop. (Or click on a mobile device.)
    <div id="app"></div>
    <div id="app"></div>
    <div id="app"></div>
    <div id="app"></div>
    <div id="app"></div>
</div>
</div>
```

Is there a way to make this work on a mobile device?
Thank you.

Comment: You can use media queries, refer this link https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries

Comment: @Anand I am using media quearys,  i need to make the div scroll.